# DownloadManager for Android: how to resume download after lost connection?

Tags: android, download, resume

I am using DownloadManager to manage downloads in my application. The public API says:

> The download manager will conduct the download in the background,
>   taking care of HTTP interactions and **retrying downloads after failures**
>   or across connectivity changes and system reboots

However, when I lost 3G / WiFi connection and it comes back again, the download is not resumed, and checking the status value it says "STATUS FAILED" with reason "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME".

Is there any way to resume a current download after losing connection with DownloadManager?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The problem could be server side: Some servers do not support resuming a download.

Comment: Also, depending on how long you lost connectivity, `DownloadManager` could have given up retrying. To resume one, I presume you request a fresh download, using a fresh `DownloadManager.Request` object.